# How to pass mask into cv::convertScaleAbs?

Tags: opencv, mask

I want to save some CPU and not to iterate thourgh pixels out of my rectangle of interest.
How can I safely extend function cv::convertScaleAbs to pass 8bit mask into it?

Comment: What is a type of the matrix you're operating on?

Comment: In my case it is CV_32UF

Answer (score 0):

You should first get the masked image (e.g. `maskedImage`) out by:

```
inputImage.copyTo(maskedImage, mask);
```

And then, simply pass this masked image (i.e. `maskedImage`) to `cv::convertScaleAbs()`.

Comment: This will still require inputImage.rows * inputImage.cols number of calls to std::abs, min an max.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO there is no posibilty to pass 8bit mask to cv::convertScaleAbs but you can always use Mat::operator() to work only on the roi itself:

```
convertScaleAbs(imgfc3(roi), outputScaled, 255.0);
```

I'm pretty sure it is not iterating over pixels you are not interested in. But it has disadvantage that it requires copying.

... and it turned out yes you can pass the same argument to convertScaleAbs and it's working:

```
Mat r = imgfc3(roi);
convertScaleAbs(r, r, 255.0);
```

But stil it does a copy.

Comment: My region of interest is not a rectangle, but a ring made of two circle r1>r2 and has area <5% of overall image.

Comment: Okay so as I said i find no possibility to do that with the opencv api. Why don't you write manually your own version of convertScaleAbs with a 8 bit mask? It shouldn't be so tricky.